# error: ')' expected not a statement

Tags: java

The following line of code is giving me a compilation error: `')'` expected not a statement `';'`

```
execute("CREATE METRIC " + sFactName + " IN FOLDER "+ sMetricFolder
 + "EXPRESSION 'sum([" + sFactName + "])' ON PROJECT"" + sProjectName +";"");
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the backslash escape character `\` around your two quotes if you wish it to print "sProjectName" at the end. Your fixed expression should read:

```
execute("CREATE METRIC " + sFactName + " IN FOLDER "+ sMetricFolder 
+ "EXPRESSION 'sum([" + sFactName + "])' ON PROJECT\"" + sProjectName +"\";");
```